# Ajax response full calendar view page issue

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Here is the relevant code:

VIEW PAGE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("click", ".calendarview", function () {  

        var roomid = $(this).data('id');
        //alert(roomid);exit;

         $('#calendar_view').fullCalendar({
            //events: [
    //          {
    //                  title: 'All Day Event',
    //                  start: roomid
    //              }
    //                  ]
            events: {
            url: base_url+'home/calview',
                dataType: 'json',
               data: {roomid: roomid},
               type: 'POST', // Send post data
               error: function() {
                 alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
               }
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
function calview()
       {
                    $room_id =$this->input->post('roomid');
                    $events=$this->Home_model->find_room_availability($room_id); 
                        $data_events = array();
                        foreach($events as $r) {
                    $data_events[] = array(
            //"title" => $r->available,
                    "description" => 'available',
                    "start" => $r->dt);
                        }
                echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
                exit();
        }
```

MODEL:

```
function find_room_availability($room_id){
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT x.dt , r.room_cnt - COALESCE(SUM(`booking_cnt`),0) available FROM calendar_table x LEFT JOIN bookinglist y ON x.dt >= y.`date_from` AND x.dt < y.`date_to` LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.id=$room_id WHERE x.dt BETWEEN now() - interval 3 month AND now() + interval 5 month GROUP BY dt ");                                           
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
    //exit;
  return $result->result();     

}
```

Ajax response is like

```
[[{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-26"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-27"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-28"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-29"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-04-30"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-01"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-02"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-03"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-04"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-05"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-06"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-07"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-08"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-09"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-10"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-11"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-12"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-13"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-14"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-15"},
{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-16"},{"title":"10","start":"2017-05-17"},}]]
```

can anyone please help me to find a solution

Comment: try to change from `base_url+'home/calview',` to  `'<?=base_url();?>home/calview',`

Comment: tried that way also always getting error message in alert

Comment: are you using any plugin for **fullCalendar** if yes then provide me documentation link..

Comment: @KundanPrasad almost certainly it means this: https://fullcalendar.io/. I've added the appropriate tag as an edit.

Comment: @Aswathi "There was an error while fetching events"  is just your arbitrary string and tells us nothing about your problem. You might as well have written `alert("The sky is blue");`, it would be no more or less useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: You need to check your browser's developer console and network tab for the _real_ error to see what is going on. You can also report the error in the GUI if you use jQuery's "error" function properly - see the method signature documented here: api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )`. Then you can actually see the real error. A HTTP status code and any error message would be the most useful information to give us.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array within an array, which fullCalendar cannot understand. It expects a single array of events.

This is the problem:

```
echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
```

Since `$data_events` is already an array, there's no need to wrap it inside another one.

```
echo json_encode($data_events);
```

should be sufficient, and produce the format that fullCalendar is expecting.

N.B. There also appears to be a stray extra bracket at the end of your JSON sample: `,}]]` but I'm assuming this is just a typo.